# Processing fields from an existing text file in Java

Tags: java, java-io

I am relatively new to Java and I've been assigned a little homework that sounds like this:

From a text file that has a number of x lines of text with the following model:

An integer || A string || Another string, define a class that deserializes those fields from the .txt file and transforms them into sets of models, fields that I need to process and then serialize them back to the .txt file.

I still didn't manage to understand how to do that from an already existing text file which has ~100 lines.

Can someone give me a hint or an article which I probably missed?

Comment: I don't think this is related to java serialization. You need to take a look at `File` and `BufferedReader` api for file reading. The idea is more on read the file line by line and process the line.

Comment: If you dont know on which lines you would encounter text or digits - I think that is a problem which would involve usage of regex. Its not a serialization related problem. Serialization is implemented when you want to transport an object.

Comment: @Bogdan please share your file along with what you have done so far to find the solution that is required

Comment: There is no [tag:serialization] here. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Read the lines 1 by 1, retrieve the integer and the two strings, use them to instanciate a class that represent the items (you will want it to have a constructor which accepts an integer and two strings). Tadam, you're done. As others said, the use of the term deserialization is a little bit confusing, as it would imply the content of your file is the result of the serialization of previously existing java objects. That said it's not incorrect either, its common use just implies a situation that isn't yours.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in yur txt file you something like this:

```
1||a||b
2||text||more text
```

you would read it like this:

```
public class FileReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String csvFile = "/path/to/input/file.txt";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = "||";
        List<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<Model>();

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
                String[] line = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

               Model model = new Model(Integer.valueOf(line[0]), line[1], line[2]);
               modelList.add(model)

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class Model {
        private int intValue;
        private String stringValue1;
        private String stringValue2;

        public Model(int intValue,
        String stringValue1,
        String stringValue2) {
            this.intValue = intValue;
            this.stringValue1 = stringValue1;
            this.stringValue2 = stringValue2;
        }

        //getters
    }

}
```

This code is based on [this tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/).

Once you have a list of models it's pretty easy to generate a list of strings and then to write it to file.